# How to dynamically determine the UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say I have a CustomTableView which extends UITableView, what I want to do is :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *idStr = @"id";
    MyTblCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:idStr];
    if (!cell) cell = [[MyTblCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:id1];
return cell;
}
```

I want the class type MyTblCell to be determined when I intialize the CustomTableView, something like the init method of the cell of the UICollectionView:

```
[collectionView registerClass:<#(__unsafe_unretained Class)#> forCellWithReuseIdentifier:<#(NSString *)#>]
```

But I don`t know how to go on when I get the class type of the cell. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Do you want to override the default implementation of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` or do you want to implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in your class rather than in a datasource class?

Comment: I mean , for example , I have Cell1 Cell2 ... which extends UITableViewCell. And when I init the CustomTableView , I want to tell it the Type of Cell to be init(replace the "MyTblCell"). This is my requirement. @Paulw11

Comment: Are you using storyboard ? and do you have any xib file or custom class for "MyTblCell" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever since iOS 6, you could register a cell class for a table view cell reuse identifier:

```
[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * identifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    // do something with the cell (no need for a nil check)
    return cell;
}
```

If you don't know the type of the cell, I would abstract your cell classes so they share methods from a superclass and have different implementations so at least you could have a type in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` versus just using `id`.

```
- (instancetype)init {

    // ...
    [tableView registerClass:[CustomCellClassSubclass class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    // ...

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * identifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCellClass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    // use some CustomCellClass methods
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! But one more problem comes here, how to call a static method of CustomCellClass to be the method of CustomCellClassSubclass: [CustomCellClass method].

Comment: You should use the newer form of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdenitifier:forIndexPath:` as this will never return nil

Comment: I can't see why you would use a class method - as you point out this will cause problems with inheritance. Just use an instance method

Comment: @Paulw11, the older form, dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:, will also never return nil if you register a class or nib, or make your cell in the storyboard (assuming you assign the identifier). The only difference between those two methods is that the older one can return nil (if you don't have an identifier or pass an incorrect one), whereas the newer method will crash if it can't return a cell.